# $.post function, return is empty

Tags: javascript, json, .post

I have a problem wit a $.post request. No errors, but the return is empty. Before I start bugging the server admin, of who the service is, with this problem. I want to make sure I did not make any mistake myself.

Below the code I'm using:

```
var post_data = JSON.stringify({'str_action':'log_element', 'int_id':'TEST', 'str_value':'EMPTY'});
$.post('http://url/', post_data, debug_return_data);

function debug_return_data(data)
{
    alert(data);
}
```

Problem is that the returned data in the alert is empty. Did I make any mistake in my code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot make Ajax calls to external URLs.

Comment: Do you have an error in the console ? If the url of the post is different from the url of your webpage, it's seems to be a cross-domain policy restriction.

Comment: if it is the cross-domain problem, look at jsonp.

Comment: A cross-domain request would cause an error, though.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is that I cannot make a Server-to-Server request, it needs to be a Client-to-Server request because the Server needs a JS session that is created in a JS login call before (JS and the rest is hosted by the other party). Correct me if I'm wrong. But with a SJONP request I need to make a server-to-server request using PHP?

Comment: you can do it with jquery but i don't know if supports post params: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Ajax call looks correct, check the response in firebug or chrome dev tools to make sure the server is actually returning data.

If you are making the AJAX call to anther server other than the one in the address bar it will be blocked as a cross-domain call.  Use JSONP if you want to do this:

http://devlog.info/2010/03/10/cross-domain-ajax/

Comment: firebug -> console tab and in the code if(console) console.log(data)

Comment: I was actually thinking using the Network tab which allows you to inspect the Request/Response headers.

Comment: Everyone above, thanks for the feedback. But I'm facing a problem not being able to make a server-to-server request (using PHP). See my comment in the first post.

Answer (score -1):

```
$.post('http://url/', post_data, function(data)
{
    alert(data);
});
```

this is in the jquery documentation

Comment: this is the same, just inlining the callback.